# Write an SQL query to get every day's "end of day" balance for each "customer - account" combination

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
CREATE TABLE "customer_account_info" (
  "customer_id" bigint,
  "account_number" bigint,
  "transaction_time" timestamp,
  "balance" float
);
```

Columns definition is as below

```
customer_id - Unique customer ID for each customer
account_number - Unique account number for each account
transaction_time - timestamp column for Date and Time of each transaction
balance - Balance of the account after the transaction
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: customer_account_info

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

i think it may help you

```
select sum(balance), account_number
from customer_account_info
where convert(date,transaction_time) = convert(date,getdate())
group by account_number
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we hope the `to_date()` function will be useful to you.

After determining how the date format should be with the to_date function, the end of day report of the desired day can be obtained.

```
SELECT account_number, SUM(balance) 
FROM customer_account_info 
WHERE transaction_time LIKE to_date ('16/12/2020','DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with MySql and it worked

```
Select 
  customer_id,
  account_number,
  Date(transaction_time) as Day,
  balance as End_of_Day_Balance
  
From
  customer_account_info
Group By
  customer_id,
  account_number,
  Date(transaction_time)
Order By
  transaction_time desc 
;
```

I guess this one is for Jash Data Science

Answer (score 1):

This one works in MySQL

```
SELECT customer_id, account_number, DAY(transaction_time) AS date_of_month, balance as end_of_day_balance
FROM customer_account_info
WHERE transaction_time IN (SELECT MAX(transaction_time) FROM customer_account_info GROUP BY customer_id, account_number, DAY(transaction_time))
GROUP BY customer_id, account_number,date_of_month;
```